# Rails - check if record exists in has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many

I'm not sure if my question is worded correctly.

I have three models: `User`, `Item`, and `UserItem`.

```
user has_many :user_items
user has_many :items, through :user_items

item has_many :user_items
item has_many :users -> {uniq}, through :user_items
item belongs_to :user

user_item belongs_to :user
user_item belongs_to :item
```

I need a way to see if a user has an item to make `if` statements in my item views  But here's the catch, user_items have `enum status: [ :pending, approved]`.  So I need to see if a `current_user` has a certain `:pending` item.

For example when a user visits item1's view page I have the item_controller's show action declare `@item = Item.find_by_id(params[:id])`.  But then what can I do with this `@item` to see if a user has this item?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try:

```
current_user.items.exists?(params[:id])
```

Or

```
current_user.items.exists?(@item.id)
```

Answer (score 7):

Extending @lei-liu's answer here. One can find if the record exists among the many or not, through: `current_user.items.exists?(params[:id])`

At the same time, `exists?` allows one to filter through the columns besides `id`, and also allows for more complicated conditions, like the following:

```
current_user.items.exists?('id > 3')
current_user.items.exists?(name: 'some_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

> But then what can I do with this @item to see if a user has this item?

I think what you are missing here is model methods. For example, if you added a method to the Item model called belongs_to_user_in_pending_state, you'd be able to call `@item.belongs_to_user_in_pending_state(current_user)` anywhere you need it.

```
def belongs_to_user_in_pending_state(user)
  if self.user_items.pending.select {|s| s.user == user}.count > 0 
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: This wasn't written to be something to copy and paste, it was written as an example to show the OP how to write and use a model method... and how to use his pending enumerator. 

The select call is a little wasteful given the uniq limitation, but someone else has already shown how to check if something exists. 

Way to hate without offering anything of value @AndreyDeineko.

Comment: 1) you do not need `self`. 2) `select` would load the whole pending user_items collection into memory prior evaluating the block, thus, having tons records in collection it could potentially overwhelm the memory. 3) in this case you do not need to `return`. 4) you could just leave the `user_items.pending.select {|s| s.user == user}.count > 0` since it will already return the boolean value. 5) sorry for the form of my first comment - it was the very morning - apologies

Comment: @AndreyDeineko You mentioned a "conventional" way to accomplish this.  What would that be?

Comment: @user4584963 by the unconventional I meant the wrong use of `return` keyword here.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko - 1+2 - I thought this was a good way to cut down the memory needs - we should only be fetching the user_items for that item, and only those that are pending... I did not know the self was unnecessary!! 3) the return habit comes from C when i took comp sci many years ago - before getting out of programming for over a decade. 4) Was thinking to set him up for more complicated functionality - agreed for this case! 5) All Good... Thanks for returning to clarify! Always enthusiastic to learn the better way!

Answer (score -1):

1) Add a scope to User_item class

```
scope :pending, -> {where status: 'pending'}
```

2) Use that scope in an instance method of Item class:

```
def is_pending_with_someone?
  self.user_items.pending.count > 0
end
```

Then you can use

```
if @item.is_pending_with_someone? 
  ...
```

Comment: I believe enum automatically adds scope

Comment: i don't think you want a count query. if you're just checking for existence using `.exists?` would give you a `SELECT ... LIMIT 1` which would stop once a match was found.