# Using a join table's row existence as an alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, arel

Given a model called Event (id, name) and a model called EventUser (event_id, user_id), I iterate through Events. During this iteration, I display whether or not the logged-in user is attending the Event based on the existence of an EventUser existing. Standard stuff.

I know that I can perform a query against each Event, and have something such as

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  def user_attending?(user)
    event_users.find_by(:user_id => user.id)
  end 

end
```

but that's not very clean, performant, or extensible.

I could load all of the User's attending events from the list of Events, say,

```
@events = Event.all 
@attending_events = current_user.event_users.where(:event_id => @events.map(&:id))
```

which is better, but not great. I could with this add an accessor to my Event model and iterate through `@attending_events` but that seems icky.

I suppose in my ideal scenario, I would be able to join the two tables on `events.id = event_users.event_id`, and where `event_users.user_id = current_user.id` and if that row exists, I'd be able to label the/a resulting column as `attending`

How can I do this with Arel or ActiveRecord, or even SQL? Using PostgreSQL over here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this? Sorry for lucky guessing, but if I didn't understood your question, could you be more concrete, which problem you're aiming to solve?

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_events, class_name: 'UserEvent', inverse_of: :event
  has_many :users, through: :user_events
end
```

#### possible kinds of usage

1) suggested usage:

`Event.joins(:user_events).where(user_events: {user_id: user.id}).any?`

2) filtering by user-details. Keep in mind that `joins` takes the defined `has_many` relation from the Event model, but `where` takes the table-name. Just in case when the `has_many` relation-name and table-name are differing

`Event.joins(:users).where(users: {name: 'Harry'}).any?`

3) alternative usage with concrete record instead of id from [Rails - check if record exists in has_many association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36490579/rails-check-if-record-exists-in-has-many-association)

`current_event.users.exists?(user.id)`

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking it could be simply:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_events, class_name: 'UserEvent', inverse_of: :event
  has_many :events, class_name: 'Event'
end
```

Then you just do 
`@attending_events = current_user.events`

In your view then you can get out whatever you store for that each `Event` which `current_user` is attending.

Answer (score -1):

I'm confused. Assuming:

- you have set up `has_many :events, through: :event_users` in your `User` model,
- you have an instance variable (presumable in your controller) something like `@user_events = user.events`
- you have an instance variable (also presumably in your controller) something like `@events = Event.all`

In your view, isn't it something like (assuming `erb`):

```
<% @events do |event| %>
  <% if @user_events.include?(event) %>
    ... do some stuff
  <% else %> 
    ... do some other stuff
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Maybe I'm being dense and entirely missing the point... If so, apologies in advance.

Comment: I think that what OP wants to do is avoid loading the user_events in another query entirely and instead add an alias to the Events query that indicates if there's a matching row based on the criteria he provided.

Comment: I'm not sure what "add an alias to the Events query" means. But, unless this is a production system with either high volume or a large number of records, this seems like a bit of preemptive optimization to me. No?