# What is the way to check if current user is associated with current post in jointable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application with User model (created with Devise gem), and Post model. Both User and Models are in relation has_and_belongs_to_many. I have join table, where I'm adding every post creator (later I will allow post creator to add more editors for the post, but it doesn't matter at this moment). The problem is when I want to check if current_user is one of users allowed to edit post.

I already tried to check if current user is included in @post.users, but it seems to be not a working solution for this problem.

```
@post.users.include?(current_user)
```

At this moment I even understand why it's not working, but i have no idea for other function checking returning bool dependent on the users_posts table in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:

Either to check with `true` or `false` as mention in this post
[Rails - check if record exists in has_many association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36490579/rails-check-if-record-exists-in-has-many-association)

**OR**

`@post.users.find(current_user.id)`

This will return either the user object if it is found or it will raise an error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`.